# How to uncapture string in regex?

Tags: regex

I would like to capture the date and time from the text below.

```
!----------------------------------------------
! 16/Oct/2020 10:11:14      12/Nov/2020 11:21:32
!----------------------------------------------
! 17/Oct/2020 10:11:14
!----------------------------------------------
! 18/Oct/2020 11:00:00      21/Oct/2020 12:00:00
!----------------------------------------------
```

My regex query:

```
(?P<StartDate>(?<=!\s)[^\s]+)\s+(?P<StartTime>[^\s]+)\s*(?P<EndDate>[^\s]+)\s+(?P<EndTime>[^\s]+)
```

However, for the second row it is capturing the exclamation mark and hyphen as well. How can I uncapture those things?

Comment: What code are you using to get the matches? I think you can [just use](https://regex101.com/r/yUVzfb/1) `^!\s(?P<StartDate>\S+) +(?P<StartTime>\S+)(?: +(?P<EndDate>\S+)(?: +(?P<EndTime>\S+))?)?` and [here is the code in Python](https://regex101.com/r/yUVzfb/1/codegen?language=python).

Comment: Does any solution here work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex. This is more specific than just the generic `[^\s]`.

*Side note, `[^\s]` can be replaced with `\S`.*

You can make the end date and time optional by wrapping them in a non-capturing group `(?:)` and then adding a question mark after it to make that group optional: `(?:)?`

###### Regex

```
(?<=!\s)(?P<StartDate>[0-3]?[0-9]\/[A-Za-z]+\/\d+)\s+(?P<StartTime>[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9])\s+(?:(?P<EndDate>[0-3]?[0-9]\/[A-Za-z]+\/\d+)\s+(?P<EndTime>[0-2]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]:[0-5]?[0-9]))?
```

**Formatted**

```regex
(?<=!\s)             # Look behind if starts with "! "
(?P<StartDate>   
    [0-3]?[0-9]
    \/
    [A-Za-z]+
    \/
    \d+
) 
\s+
(?P<StartTime>
    [0-2]?[0-9]
    :
    [0-5]?[0-9]
    :
    [0-5]?[0-9]
)
\s+
(?:                   # non capturing group
    (?P<EndDate>
       [0-3]?[0-9]
       \/
       [A-Za-z]+
       \/
       \d+
    )
    \s+
    (?P<EndTime>
        [0-2]?[0-9]
        :
        [0-5]?[0-9]
        :
        [0-5]?[0-9]
    )
)?                   # Make this group optional
```

###### Demo

https://regex101.com/r/Ky7g45/1

###### Cons

This will also match invalid dates from 32 - 39 and time hours from 24 - 29. If that matters, you'll need to add more regex with the `|` operator.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your capture groups optional (at least the end time/date).

```
(?P<StartDate>(?<=!\s)[^\s]+)\s+(?P<StartTime>[^\s]+)\s*(?P<EndDate>[^!\s]+)?\s+(?P<EndTime>[^!\s]+)?
```

Here I make the `EndDate` and `EndTime` capture groups optional and also explicitely exclude exclamation marks (this is another avenue to explore, making the capture groups more specific to match only a date/time and not any non-whitespace characters).

For example, the dates can be matched with

```
[0-9]{2}\/[A-Za-z]{3}\/[0-9]{4}
```

and the times with

```
[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}
```

Answer (score 1):

A pretty similar RegExp of yours
with a lookbehind `(?<=)` and an *optional* non-capturing group `(?:)?`:

```sh
(?<=!\s)(?P<StartDate>\S+)\s+(?P<StartTime>\S+)(?:\s+(?P<EndDate>\S+)\s+(?P<EndTime>\S+))?
```

**Description and example at: [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2uEUBd/3)**